# How do I dynamically change initial form values based on a value selected by the user? Django

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I would like certain fields in my form to be populated based on a selected value in one of the fields. I have found examples on dynamic form generation, but not on this...

Here is my `models.py`

```
class Module(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")

class Class(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
```

and my `forms.py`

```
class inputClassInformation(forms.Form):
    module = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Module.objects.all())
    duration = forms.CharField(disabled=True, required=False)
    description = forms.CharField()
```

To re-iterate, the desired result would be:
Based on the module selected by the user, the duration is automatically pulled from the entry in the database and is shown in the corresponding form field.

I've not been able to find an example online/in the documentation on this, so help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can do it using JS. Listen event "on change select field", then send request to server via jquery, for example, on response fill field description.

Comment: @VladimirGoncharuk I'm not too sure how I can fill in the form fields using JS. Sounds like I'll have to be able to identify each field by a css selector and set the initial text values for all...

Answer (score 0):

You could put the module selection inside its own submit form and on submit passing the module to your view in views.py, then getting the initial values for duration and description and passing the initial values to your form as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260030/django-set-initial-value-with-a-passed-variable). This solution would work without javascript but needs a submit button next to your module drop down.